# Как применить map, к массиву с вложенными объектами?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

Вопрос заключается в получении значения, из массива вложенных объектов.
Я хочу заменить вот эту строку    `<p>{current.car[0].model}</p>`,на более динамическую, что бы отображались все значения model, которые есть у вложенных объектов массива car.
Если же введу просто `<p>{current.car.model}</p>` то ничего не отображается на странице, так как выдает в консоли undefined

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const fakeDB = [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "Carl",
      age: 45,
      height: 170,
      car: [
        {
          id: "2",
          model: "mazda",
          color: "blue",
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          model: "toyota",
          color: "black",
        },
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {fakeDB.map((current, key) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{current.name}</p>
            <p>{current.car[0].model}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr = []
 fakeDB[0].car.forEach((item) => arr.push(item.model))  // вытаскиваем все значения по ключу model из вложенных в массив car обьектов

const result = arr.map(item =>  `<p> ${item}<p>`)
console.log(result)  // ["<p> mazda<p>", "<p> toyota<p>"]
```

можно так.

Comment: Ну это мне кажется неплохо:)Спасибо Вам)